# How to create custome tabs like below image?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

[image]

How to create this type of tabs with tab control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for Mutlinline tabs.

Use [`TabControl.Multiline Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.multiline(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether more than one row of tabs can
>   be displayed.

Comment: Where to use multiline property and how to write?

Comment: @Elixir, in either design time or in code, Look at the code example in the linked msdn article.